# How to detect landmarks of multiple faces using OpenCV and Tensorflow model?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, detection

I would like to ask how can I detect eye landmarks of more than a face in real-time using OpenCV and Tensorflow.
So I have the trained frozen model that can predict the eye region landmarks.
I have successfully detected landmarks on one face using python script with the OpenCV library, also the script detects multiple faces. But landmarks are drawn only on one face.

How Can get landmarks of multiple detected faces?

```py
    cam=cv2.VideoCapture('C:\\Users\\User\\cnn-facial-landmark\\vidtest.mp4')
    while True:
        # Read frame
        frame_got, frame = cam.read()
        if frame_got is False:
            break
        frame = frame[0:480, 300:940]
        frame_cnn = frame.copy()

        # CNN benchmark.
        facebox = extract_face(frame_cnn)
        if facebox is not None:
            face_img = frame[
                facebox[1]: facebox[3],
                facebox[0]: facebox[2]]

            # Detect landmarks
            face_img = cv2.resize(face_img, (INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE))
            face_img = cv2.cvtColor(face_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img=np.array(face_img).reshape(1,INPUT_SIZE,INPUT_SIZE,3)
            landmarks = detect_marks(img, sess, detection_graph)

            # Visualization of the result.
            origin_box_size = facebox[2] - facebox[0]
            for mark in landmarks:
                mark[0] = facebox[0] + mark[0] * origin_box_size
                mark[1] = facebox[1] + mark[1] * origin_box_size
                cv2.circle(frame_cnn, (int(mark[0]), int(
                    mark[1])), 1, (255, 255, 255), -1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow("Preview", frame_cnn)
        writer.write(frame_cnn)
        if cv2.waitKey(30) == 27:
            break

    sess.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You contradict yourself; Is the issue with detection, or with drawing?

Comment: The issue is with drawing landmarks on the more than one face, So landmarks can be drawn on just one face when a video showing more than the face.